# Footer not shown on tablet in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I cant figure out why footer of my app is shown on phone but not on tablet.

Here is layout for footer:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_devicescreenlogo"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/version"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:paddingStart="2dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/light_grey"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

On phone (4.6") it looks like this:
[image: Phone]

And on tablet (7") picture is not shown only version:
[image]

Do you have idea what is wrong?

Thank you

[EDIT]

Here is picture that I use: [image: waves]

Answer (score 1):

Well that code should pretty much work, I have tried it on my emulator and it works just fine with 7 inch screen, try to get actual devices and see if that solves the problem

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/arsenal"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/version"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:paddingStart="2dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/darkgray"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: And Im just asumming you are putting your code inside a RelativeLayout

Comment: In layout preview it is shown expected too but on device tablet Nexus 7 image is not shown. Can there be problem with image itself? That it needs some bigger format or something?

Comment: Well you might be right, please share the image you are using, or better still try using atlist three different images to see how it pans out..

Comment: and also try to change imageview to this

Comment: <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_devicescreenlogo"
        />

Comment: android:scaleType="centerCrop" didnt help. I have added that picture too.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use this code.. its work fine.
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/version"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:paddingStart="2dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout

> Blockquote
```

Comment: It would be nice if you explain why the author get its error and how your answer correct it

Comment: This didnt help and it would version would be placed below image. I want it over.

Answer (score 0):

Add parent Relative layout gravity bottom.

```
android:layout_gravity="bottom"

<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/footer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="45dp"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
```